# No data in params on POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular

Currently I have a problem with an Angular2 and RoR5 API. I'm trying to save an object to the API Server, but this doesn't work.

Here is my Angular2 Code for the service:

```
createFrame(frameData) {
   let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
   let body = JSON.stringify({frame: frameData});
   return this.http.post(this.frameURL, body, headers).map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

The request is made by my browser and I can see the JSON Data:
[image]

But RoR is not able to get the POST Data.

```
[1] pry(#<Api::V1::FramesController>)> params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"format"=>:json, "controller"=>"api/v1/frames", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
[2] pry(#<Api::V1::FramesController>)>
```

Can someone tell me, what's wrong?

Comment: Looks like you may need to [permit](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) `title`, `is_photolini`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you set the content type for form data and you send some content with the JSON format.

Either you use send form data or JSON content.

- **Form data**

  ```
  createFrame(frameData) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let form = new URLSearchParams();
    form.set('param1', 'some value');
    let body = form.toString();
    return this.http.post(this.frameURL, body, headers).map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
  ```
- **JSON data**

  ```
  createFrame(frameData) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let form = new URLSearchParams();
    form.set('param1', 'some value');
    let body = form.toString();
    return this.http.post(this.frameURL, body, headers).map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had a similar solution, but it didn't work. Now I found the problem. In the return line, I pass the header variable to the post method. It has to be options instead. May be you can change your solution, so it might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be related to CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing)

Thy to enable in your application -->
[Enabling cors Rails5](http://sourcey.com/building-the-prefect-rails-5-api-only-app/#enabling-cors)

Good luck